# Icon of MediaItem does not show on Android Auto

Tags: android, android-auto

I am trying to set the icon of MediaItem using setIconBitmap(). The icon displays when I open the left navigation menu/left drawer for the first time, but it cannot show when I reopen the menu. If I click a browserable mediaItem, display a sub-menu, and goes back to the main menu, the icon shows up again. The problem is only in the head unit, everything displays in the Android Auto app on the phone.

```
 MediaDescription description = new MediaDescription.Builder().setTitle("abc")
                .setSubtitle("xyz").setIconBitmap(bitmap)
                .setMediaId(itemId).build();
 MediaBrowser.MediaItem item = new MediaBrowser.MediaItem(description, MediaBrowser.MediaItem.FLAG_PLAYABLE);
 mediaItems.add(item);
 result.send(mediaItems);
```

The icon displays perfect if I change to setIconUri(), but I have to use setIconBitmap().